# Can i call a function inside a created contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, web3js, contract-invocation, dapp-development

I have a structure similar like this typical Factory.

```
contract Factory {
  bytes32[] Names;
  address[] newContracts;

  function createContract (bytes32 name) {
      address newContract = new Contract(name);
      newContracts.push(newContract);
  } 

  function getName (uint i) {
      Contract con = Contract(newContracts[i]);
      Names[i] = con.Name();
  }
}

contract Contract {
  bytes32 public Name;
  string public numberString;

  function Contract (bytes32 name) {
      Name = name;
  }

  function setNumberString (string time){
      numberString = time;      
  }
}
```

I added to this structure the function `setNumberString` and the variable `numberString`, with [Web3 js](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API) i have defined this:

```
myContract = web3.eth.contract(ABIArray).at(contractAddress);
myContract.setNumberString(state, function(error, result){
 if(!error)
     console.log(result)
 else
     console.error(error);
 })
```

The `ABIArray` and `contractAddress` are of the "contract Contract" created, and when i try to call the function, i obtain this message in the browser of the Dapp:

```
Uncaught TypeError: myContract.setNumberString is not a function
```

When i try to do this with a normal contract i don't have any problem, what i'm doing wrong? Is possible to call the function of this created contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may occur because `setNumberString` is not defined in your ABI.

Try using this

```
ABIArray=[{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"time","type":"string"}],"name":"setNumberString","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"Name","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"numberString","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"name","type":"bytes32"}],"payable":false,"type":"constructor"}];
```

Comment: Nice fixed it, my ABIArray was wrong. I can acces to `string public numberString; `? with `myContract.numberString`? or i need to modified the ABI array again?

Comment: access it with myContract.numberString()